# Load object from model on every page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to load a single (chosen randomly) object from a single table in my database on every page of my rails app.

For example, a quotes table which has several quotes in the table, and I just want one on every page load.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Obviously copy & pasting the query into each controller isn't the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `before_filter` for this, there is no need to access database on redirecting actions and other "not rendered" actions. Instead I would use `helper_function`, and I would call it in the layout, as you need to position it anyways.

```
def random_quote
  @quote ||= "Select random quote here"
end

helper_method :random_quote
```

Your method of selecting a quote is up to you. You just need to access `random_quote` as a normal helper method in the layout. This only access one quote per action, only if the layout is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff typically goes into a `before_filter` in the ApplicationController :

```
before_filter :get_random_quote

#This code is executed before every action of your app
def get_random_quote
  random_id = ...#Generate a random ID ...
  @random_quote = Quote.find(random_id)
end
```

Then in your views, just refer to `@random_quote`. Done!

Edit : on second thought, Matzi solution seems smarter. The request will only get called when you actually output something. Nothing's wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PostgreSQL:

```
before_filter :get_quote

def get_quote
  @quote = Quote.order('RANDOM()').limit(1)
end
```